# What are the factors that may explain why there's a much higher cap set by Canada for Ukrainian temporary visa holders than Palestinians?

Tags: canada, refugees

https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/manitoba/gaza-visa-winnipeg-reaction-1.7076386

> On Dec. 21, Marc Miller, Canada's federal minister responsible for
> immigration and refugees, announced the new program to help people
> fleeing the war. It offers visas to 1,000 Palestinians, which would
> allow them to take refuge in Canada for three years if their families
> are willing to support them financially.

https://nationalpost.com/news/canada/program-for-ukrainians-seeking-to-come-to-canada-ends-this-month

> Ukrainians had until last July to apply for the program and have until
> the end of March to arrive in Canada. Since the program began, 960,000
> people have been approved to come to Canada, but as of the end of
> February only about 250,000 people had arrived.
>
> Ihor Michalchyshyn, CEO and executive director of the Ukrainian
> Canadian Congress, said they have seen an increase in Ukrainians using
> the visas in the last few weeks.

What are the factors that may explain why there's a much higher cap set by Canada for Ukrainian temporary visa holders than Palestinians? It seems that the article mentions that some Palestinians don't have any documentation because they fled the country as fast as they could, but to me it doesn't really explain why they've put a cap of 1,000 visa holders, because even if a lot of them don't have any documentation, you don't need to set a hard limit and try to accept as many of them as long they have the proper documentation.

Comment: Gaza population is about 1/20th of the Ukrainian population, so the 15-25K number quoted in the article sounds about right, if measured proportionally. But the requirement is also to have family in Canada willing to sponsor, so the question is whether there are also similar rates of Palestinians in Canada as there are Ukrainians, and whether they have the same economic capacity to sponsor.

Comment: Not my DV, but there are/were wars going on in Ethiopia, Sudan, or Yemen. (Far more deadly than Gaza, one might [add](https://www.newstatesman.com/world/2024/02/forgotten-wars-ethiopia-tigray-sudan).) And Canada didn't invite in millions of those people either. So, the answer should be a bit obvious.

Comment: There's also a big element that doing so would be playing to the ["voluntary emigration" lot](https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-uk-slam-inflammatory-call-by-israeli-minister-smotrich-voluntary-emigration-of-gaza/).  We let in 35000 Syrians, which wasn't very generous.  Quite possibly we should let in more Gazans, *later*, with a proper two state solution in place.  Not *now*, to facilitate removals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exceptional figure here is for Ukraine. Comparing Gaza with other Africa or Middle East conflicts and Canada's response:

- 2016 ["IOM Sudan Resettles 1,750 Refugees to Canada"](https://www.iom.int/news/iom-sudan-resettles-1750-refugees-canada). And [674 in 2023](https://www.hrw.org/news/2024/03/13/sudanese-refugee-deaths-highlight-eu-policy-failures).
- 2023 ["IOM Ethiopia Resettles Over 320 Refugees to Canada"](https://ethiopia.iom.int/news/iom-ethiopia-resettles-over-320-refugees-canada)
- ["As of February 28, 2023, Canada has resettled 532 refugees from Yemen since 2017"](https://www.ourcommons.ca/petitions/en/Petition/Details?Petition=e-3899#:%7E:text=As%20of%20February%2028%2C%202023,risk%20from%20around%20the%20world.).

Keep also in mind also that those conflicts [were](https://www.newstatesman.com/world/2024/02/forgotten-wars-ethiopia-tigray-sudan) more deadly overall than the one in Gaza thus far.

One can advance some guesses why Ukraine was treated differently, but I'll leave that to others.

Anyhow, there's a bit of difference in status too. While one might think that it was purely window dressing that Ukrainians were not officially labelled refugees, it does seem to make wee bit of a difference [on some](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/new-brunswick/ukrainian-refugee-canada-ukraine-authorization-for-emergency-travel-1.6498928) financial matters:

> People coming in through this program are considered temporary residents. This means they can work and study in Canada for three years. However, unlike refugees, they don't have permanent residency when they land, they don't get social assistance in some provinces, would have to pay international students fees if they want to go to university, and at first had no settlement support.

Interestingly some Afghan refugees in Canada (which actually seem to be more numerous than those from the 3 countries I mentioned in the bullets above--40,000 [according to IOM](https://www.iom.int/news/more-40000-afghans-resettled-canada-ioms-support)) [have sued](https://globalnews.ca/news/9935623/2nd-afghan-canadian-refugees-lawsuit-ukraine/) the Canadian government [in 2023], claiming discrimination from Ukrainians. I'm not sure how that ended.

Comment: how come the question was downvoted?

Comment: Interestingly, Syria was also treated exceptionally, although Canada didn't have troops there IIRC (maybe participated in the anti-ISIS campaign though). One [source](https://refuge.journals.yorku.ca/index.php/refuge/article/view/41034/36868) says 70,000 Syrians were resettled in Canada, but other source on the web float just 40,000, so I'm not entirely sure about that one.

Comment: @Sayaman I DV'ed the question for the reason indicated in my comment under the Q.  We've had several such why-not-as-many-as-Ukraine, or why-Gazans-unwanted, questions in the past.  Gaza is not a strict equivalent to other refugee crisis and that has already been answered several times before.  And, yes, let's not kid ourselves, there is also the (small? big?) factor that Western countries are a bit more attuned to Ukrainians' plight than they are to other groups.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from just humanitarian help, hosting refugees is part af the assistance to the country at war. Canada is willing to provide this assistance to Zelenskyy but not for Hamas leaders.

Comment: That doesn't make that much sense.  Hamas leaders, if they chose exile to spare regular Gazans from living a war zone, could easily find a host country willing to take them in on that status (that would pull the chestnuts out of the fire more for many Western governments).  They *wouldn't* risk coming in as normal refugees, with the possibility of subsequent extradition once identified.